# PHP : send http post request but "Authentication failed"

Tags: php, http-post

I'm trying to log in to a website, but receive an "Authentication failed" error, as if I were wrong using the username or password. The passed parameters are correct, including username and password, as I developed the same code in Java and it works. Am I making a mistake when sending the fields?

```
$cookies = array();
foreach ($http_response_header as $hdr) {
    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]+)/', $hdr, $matches)) {
        parse_str($matches[1], $tmp);
        $cookies += $tmp;
    }
}
$cookie= reset($cookies);

$request = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'timeout' => 0,
        'header'=> "Accept-language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3\r\n" .
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
            "User-Agent:    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6\r\n" .
            "Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=".$cookie."\r\n",
        'content' => http_build_query(array(
            '__LASTFOCUS' => '',
            '__EVENTTARGET' => '',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT' => '',
            '__VIEWSTATE' => $viewstate,
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR' => $viewstategenerator,
            'ctl00$hwsid' => $hwsid,
            'ctl00$PageSessionId' => $pagesessionid,
            'ctl00$DefaultUrl' => $defaulturl,
            'ctl00$GenericErrorUrl' => $genericerrorurl,
            'ctl00$PopupElement' => '',
            'ctl00$PollingTimeoutSecs' => $pollingtimeoutsecs,
            'ctl00$bodyContent$txtUser' => $user,
            'ctl00$bodyContent$txtPassword' => $password,
            '__CALLBACKID' => '__Page',
            '__CALLBACKPARAM' => '"hwsid="'.$hwsid.'"&PageSessionId="'.$pagesessionid.'"&DefaultUrl="'.$defaulturl.'"&GenericErrorUrl="'.$genericerrorurl.'"&PopupElement="'.'"&PollingTimeoutSecs="'.$pollingtimeoutsecs.'"&txtUser="'.$user.'"&txtPassword="'.$password,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION' => $eventvalidation,
            'ctl00$bodyContent$btnLogin' => 'Conferma'

        )),
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($request);
$res= file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo htmlentities($res);
```

The working code used for the java is as follows:

```
cookies = initialResponse.cookies();

                initialResponse = Jsoup.connect(url+"Default.aspx")
                    .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
                    .data("__EVENTTARGET", "")
                    .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
                    .data("__VIEWSTATE", executionVal)
                    .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", vv1)
                    .data("ctl00$hwsid", a11)
                    .data("ctl00$PageSessionId", a22)
                    .data("ctl00$DefaultUrl", a33)
                    .data("ctl00$GenericErrorUrl", a44)
                    .data("ctl00$PopupElement", "")
                    .data("ctl00$PollingTimeoutSecs", a66)
                    .data("ctl00$bodyContent$txtUser", user)
                    .data("ctl00$bodyContent$txtPassword", pass)
                    .data("__CALLBACKID", "__Page")
                    .data("__CALLBACKPARAM", "hwsid="+a11+"&PageSessionId="+a22+"&DefaultUrl="+a33+"&GenericErrorUrl="+a44+"&PopupElement="+"&PollingTimeoutSecs="+a66+"&txtUser="+user+"&txtPassword="+pass)
                    .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", ltVal)
                    .data("ctl00$bodyContent$btnLogin", "Conferma") 
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36")
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .timeout(0)
                    .execute();
            }catch(UnknownHostException e){
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No", "Turni", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
                 System.exit(0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            cookies.putAll(initialResponse.cookies());

            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(u)
                  .cookies(cookies)
                  .get();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: What might be helpful is looking at the final URL, cookies, and POST body; and then compare them with a working version.

Comment: I think I have understood, practically when I access the website the first cookie is generated (ASP_NET_SessionId=wpxfk3msbyghw5nlo2wlxer), once you have sent the request post with that cookie, the site issues another one to be able to access and this I think you have to add (SSOAuth=DF1D63B311125E1C34689C7D16B4BE4D798E718C1A037B189A2284797B7FFB)
 so to the post final request, cookie would add the two cookies "ASP_NET_SessionId=wpxfk3msbyghw5nlo2wlxer; SSOAuth=DF1D63B311125E1C34689C7D16B4BE4D798E718C1A037B189A2284797B7FFB", but how do I get in the code and add the second cookie?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are misusing `reset()`. It returns the value of the first array element. So if you're getting more than one cookie back, you could be in for problems. If you're looking for a specific cookie, you could do something like this:

```
// here's what we're looking for
$target = "ASP.NET_SessionId";

// filter the array
$cookies = array_filter(
    $http_response_header,
    function($v) use ($target) {return strpos($v, "Set-Cookie: $target=") === 0;}
);

if (!empty($cookies)) {
    // here we know we only have a single entry in the array
    $cookie = reset($cookies);
    $cookie = preg_replace("/.*=([^;]*)/", "$1", $cookie);
} else {
    // no cookies received!
    $cookie = "";
}
```

Really this is a lot more complicated than it needs to be though. Easiest thing to do would be to just take all the cookies and send them back in the second request:

```
$cookies = array_filter(
    $http_response_header,
    function($v) {return strpos($v, "Set-Cookie:") === 0;}
);
$headers = [
    "Accept-language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6",
];
foreach ($cookies as $cookie) {
    $headers[] = preg_replace("/^Set-/", "", $cookie);
}

$request = [
    "http" => [
        "method" => "POST",
        "timeout" => 0,
        "header"=> $headers,
        "content" => "..."
];
```

Comment: Easier still would be to use curl functions, which handle cookies for you automatically.

Comment: As I have already written before when I access the website the first cookie is generated (ASP_NET_SessionId=wpxfk3msbyghw5nlo2wlxer), once you have sent the request post with that cookie, the site issues another one to be able to access and this I think you have to add (SSOAuth=DF1D63B311125E1C34689C7D16B4BE4D798E718C1A037B189A2‌​284797B7FFB) so to the post final request, cookie would add the two cookies "ASP_NET_SessionId=wpxfk3msbyghw5nlo2wlxer; SSOAuth=DF1D63B311125E1C34689C7D16B4BE4D798E718C1A037B189A22‌​84797B7FFB", but how do I get in the code and add the second cookie?

Comment: The second code block above takes all the cookies from the response and puts them in your request.

Comment: is correct, but inserts them into another GET request, in that case. But when all cookies are retrieved for the second time, there is also the second cookie called "SSOAuth", which is not present in the POST request.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The code above takes an array of response headers and pulls all the cookies out. Put them in whatever request you want.

Comment: in the java code, after having done the same operation as in the php code, there is this other piece of code necessary to obtain the other cookie "SSOAuth" that allows you to log in to the site:     cookies.putAll(initialResponse.cookies()); Document doc = null;  try { doc = Jsoup.connect(u).cookies(cookies).get();  How do I translate it into php to get the "SSOAuth" cookie?

Comment: java code debugging image of that piece of code that also returns me the cookie "SSOAuth": https://postimg.org/image/4ramv1v42j/

Comment: in the java code there is the method "execute ();" which sends a first request post with the first cookie and then after this request the cookies that become two are again requested.